# How to make html text input where each line is a different color

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm creating a web tool that takes user input and to improve readability, I want to change each line (after \n) to a different color.

I currently have the user input in a text area. I'm very new to doing front end stuff like this, so I'm not really sure where to start. I thought about using the below javascript that I found for output to divide up the text by each line, but I can't see how this would work for user input.

```
 var lines = $("#binding-text").val().split("\n");
 for(var i = 0;i < lines.length;i++)
 {
    //code here using lines[i] which will give you each line

 }
```

Ideally, I would have each line of typed input following a new line change color as the user types. For example:

"a\n" (would appear in blue)
"ab\n" (would appear in red)
"cd\n" (would appear in green)

Comment: You can't split a textbox into multiple colors, you must use some other block element to do so which can then be styled to look like an input.

Comment: you can use `div` or `p` with contenteditable attribute and wrap each line in a new p or div and color it differently.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you considered using CSS gradients for repeating stripes? Notice I'm setting the `line-height` to be identical to the stripe height.

```css
.horizontal-stripes {
  border: solid 1px red;
  background: repeating-linear-gradient( 180deg, #fff, #fff 20px, #ccc 20px, #ccc 40px);
  height: 200px;
  width: 15em;
}

textarea {
  min-height: 10em;
  width: 15em;
  line-height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<textarea class="horizontal-stripes"></textarea>
```

[image]